# how to add transitions to a slideshow made with javascript

Tags: css

I know this question has been asked before but I can't get mine working. I have a javascript array in the head of my html document which makes the images change to the next one in the array, but I can't make transitions work. I've tried using css properties and I've very briefly tried jquery but as I haven't used jquery before I don't know how to do anything with it.

I have this for javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
image2 =new Array("images/product1_thumb.png", "images/product2_thumb.png", "images/product3_thumb.png"
, "images/product4_thumb.png")
num =0;
imgNum =image2.length;
    function rotate()
    {
        if(document.images)
        {
            if(num ==imgNum)
            {
                num = 0;
            }
        }
    document.getElementById('image2').src = image2[num];
    num++;
    setTimeout("rotate()",4000);
    }
</script>
```

This is the html:

```
<section id="right">
<img src="images/product1_thumb.png" ID="image2"  alt="" title="" />
</section>
```

And this css is what I've used to try to make the transitions:

```
#image2{
margin-left:100px;
position:inherit;
-moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out 2s;
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out 2s;
transition: all 2s ease-in-out 2s;  /*  opacity 5s ease-in-out; */
    }

#right{
padding-top:10%;
margin-left:70%;
width:30%;
background-image:url('images/watermark50.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
height:100%;
    }

#right img{
margin-left: 30%;
    }
```

I'd be grateful for any help but if it uses jquery you'd have to start at the beginning as I have no idea how it works.

Comment: if you want a fading effect, then in the round() function decrease the opacity of the <img> in a loop and then load the new image with 0 opacity and then increase its opacity in a loop

Comment: In this case transition shouldnot word

Comment: What are you trying to say ?

Comment: Any chance of getting a hint on the code that, Mevin? I'm a beginner and don't really know how these things work.